# Pearson's Correlation scores in MOLUSCE not applicable

Tags: qgis-plugins, molusce, euclidean

I think I have a problem with the input data for MOLUSCE. I don't know why the Pearson's correlation score is always near 1.0  and 1.0 (is it okay?). As I read some of the related literatures, the score's always quite far below 1.0.

Do anyone have any idea what I did wrong?

[image]